# Why do Django developers use Django builtin admin panel? is it said that must to use instead of a html theme?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I want to develop full functional web application in python django. I want to use bootstrap admin theme to develop admin site. I want to know is it required to use django admin while you are a django developer? or it's just a optional function if some one interested to complete tasks fast?

Comment: No one is forcing you to use default django admin dashboard, it's just there' if you want a quick n easy solution. Make own your admin panel if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While many people prefer to build their custom admin panel.I always prefer to use existing code and customize django admin panel.

Django admin panel gives you flexibility to view models and perform operations on them.Django Admin is fully customizable and if you want to use it you don't need an additional admin panel for your website because all the management work can be done using that.

You can go with your own admin panel, but if you want to start off quickly and use the existing functionalities, models and functions then you can quickly customize your django admin panel according to your use.

You can manage ManytoMany, OnetoMany relations  easily and can integrate different widgets according to your use which would be time taking if you build your custom admin panel.

For getting more details on how you can customize django admin panel kindly go through : [Django admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/)

You can go through this article as well to have an overview :
https://www.techiediaries.com/customize-django-admin/